# Fantasy modern-looking anime about a couple

Tags: story-identification, anime

The guy has blonde hair and the girl has purple hair. It’s
modern-looking and a supernatural anime (which included witches).

At the end she dies and the guy kisses her and she wakes up in her
bedroom. They were lovers.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For the record, it would probably be easier to identify the very few animes that don't have a supernatural girl with purple hair